# Jira automation. Reminder for users - forcing them to be active

Tags: jira

We have a problem - people who create tasks are not very actively involved in their further verification or testing. For example, we received a task, the programmer asked a question or solved a problem and submitted it for testing, and the task can wait several days until the user responds to our question or comment. The project manager has to run after them and remind them to get on with the task. It is very uncomfortable.
I want to set up an automation that will:

1. Check how much time has passed since the programmer’s last comment,
2. If more than one day has passed AND If the status of the task differs from “ready”, an automatic comment with a reminder should appear in the task and this should continue until the user leaves a comment and changes the status of the task.

I can't figure out how this can be done using automation. I would appreciate any help/advice.

I can't find how to bind to the date of the last comment from a specific user. All I found in automation was the task update date (but this doesn’t suit me).